# Re-writting a string with a click event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to program a click function that if a certain condition is true, each time the button is clicked it will overwrite the current string and replace it with a new string character.

I created a simple example below to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const hello = document.getElementById("hi");
  const button =
    document.getElementById("replace");
  let clicked = false;

  let goodBye = function() {
    clicked = true;
    if (hello.innerHTML.length < 9) {
      if (clicked) {
        // I want to clear the current HTML first, then I went the new HTML to add a single 9 every time the button is clicked.    
        hello.innerHTML += "9";
      }
    }
  }
  button.addEventListener("click", goodBye);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="hi">01234567</h1>
<button id="replace">click me</button>
```

While I'm sure this is very simple I'm still relatively new to working with JS and I've been stuck trying to figure this out for over a week now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're missing some brackets in the Javascript.

Comment: Is your javascript imported in from an external .js file or is it inlined, and if so, is it wrapped in `<script>` tags?

Comment: This will only add `9` one time. After that, the `length < 9` test will fail.

Comment: I'm writting all this in a code pen, i forgot to paste the closing brackets for the document.ready function but they are in there in my code.

Comment: What about the close brackets for `let goodbye = function() { ... }`? You have the `addEventListener` call inside the function.

Comment: You need to post code that we can actually try to run.

Comment: Your code seems to work now. I fixed a typo in the snippet (there was a missing `>` at the end of the `</button>`). What is the actual problem you're having?

Answer (score 1):

I removed your jQuery as it's not needed. I believe this is what you are looking for.

Steps:

1. Obtain a reference to your elements (`hello` and `button`)
2. Bind an event listener to your button click
3. When button is clicked, get the current value of your `hello` element
4. Run logic (`if statement`) and do what you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/3ho2by8t/14/

```js
(() => {
  const hello = document.getElementById("hi");
  const button = document.getElementById("replace");
  
  button.addEventListener('click', (evt) => { 
   const helloText = hello.innerHTML;
   if (helloText.length > 9) {
     hello.innerHTML = '9';
    } else {
     hello.innerHTML += helloText.length;
    }
  });
  
})();
```

```html
<h1 id="hi">01234567</h1>
<button id="replace">click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, you sorta have the effect I want but the conditions aren't right. You know how the display resets on a calculator when you press a number button after pressing a math operator like the plus sign for example? that's the effect I'm looking for...the length is not supposed to exceed a certain amount otherwise it overflows the display element that I have.

Comment: Please upvote if this is helpful. I think you are wanting me to solve your problem/write the code for you rather than give you direction. That is not the scope of SOF

Comment: The jQuery is needed to ensure that the code runs when the document is ready. You could replace it with the equivalent  event listener for `DOMContentLoaded`.